# 'pip' installs to wrong directory, even though it's set correctly in PATH

Tags: python-3.x, path, visual-studio-code, pip

I'm having trouble with my PATH and can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

I'm using a virtualenv on my Mac, and when I call `which pip`, it confirms this - but when I `pip install` anything, it dumps it into my 'usr/local' path.

I have `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` added to my .bash_profile to ensure that user-installed binaries take precedence, but I have `{
   "python.pythonPath": "/Virtualenvs/py3/bin/python3.7"
}` added in my VSCode settings.json to ensure the right path from there.

More specifically, calling `which pip` returns:

`/Users/username/Virtualenvs/py3/bin/pip`

But `pip install telegram`returns:

`Requirement already satisfied: telegram in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.1)`

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try pip --user to install it to particular user directories

Comment: Pip install —user <telegram> or whatever  package you are trying to install. Post back the error

Comment: I've tried:

`python3 -m pip install --user /Users/username/Virtualenvs/py3/bin telegram`

`pip install --user /Users/username/Virtualenvs/py3/bin/python3.7 telegram`

`pip install --install-option="--prefix=/Users/username/Virtualenvs/py3/bin/python3.7" telegram`

as well as just about every other combination I can think of, resulting in a range of errors from:

`It looks like a path. File 'Users/username/Virtualenvs/py3/bin/python3.7' does not exist.`

to:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

Nothing works.

Comment: `pip install --user telegram` returns `Requirement already satisfied: telegram in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.1)`

Comment: I've also tried reinstalling telegram, with no luck.

Comment: Have you installed virtualevn correctly? Follow the guide here https://gist.github.com/pandafulmanda/730a9355e088a9970b18275cb9eadef3

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by adding:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Virtualenvs/py3/bin/python3.7",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "[python]": {

    },
```

to:
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
as well as:
/Users/username/Virtualenvs/test_env/build/.vscode/settings.json

It's not a perfect solution, as it will require me to change the settings.json file each time I switch environments.

If anyone has an answer that won't - I'd love to hear it.